# Docker daemon not starting on embedded

Tags: linux, iptables, docker, embedded

I am unable to run docker daemon on my embedded device using a custom Linux distro (Yocto based). The initialization ends with the following error:

> failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: Error creating default "bridge" network: Failed to program NAT chain: Failed to inject DOCKER in PREROUTING chain: iptables failed: iptables --wait -t nat -A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER: iptables v1.8.3 (legacy): Couldn't load match `addrtype':No such file or directory

Kernel version `5.4.70-2.3.2+g8c73bc6`

Docker version `19.03.2-ce, build 6a30dfc`

Any ideas on what to try?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It says what’s the problem in the error message though? Your (custom?) kernel does not support the required IPTables match types. You can have them either as kernel modules or built-in.

Comment: So to say it again: it's about the kernel configuration options, not about the kernel version. You'll have to recompile the kernel, possibly multiple times until all prerequisites are present. (If I could have found a web page about all prerequisites I would have made an answer instead of this comment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a coincidence, I've being doing this myself.

There's a script provided by the moby project that can help you figure it out what is missing on your kernel to support docker.
You can find it [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/contrib/check-config.sh).

Download the file

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moby/moby/master/contrib/check-config.sh
```

Make it executable

```
chmod +x check-config.sh
```

And run

```
./check-config.sh
```

Then you'll have to include what's missing and rebuild your kernel.